# How can I search through a single sharepoint List in a site collection using Search Scope?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have added a `Web Address` rule to a `Search Scope` and set the `Folder` url to the following for searching through a single list in site collection :-

http://svrmosstest3/sites/asmtportal/Lists/SearchList

And added this scope to the search dropdown, this search is working fine and will return results from that list only, but it returns one extra item which is an entry for the list itself which is :-

http://svrmosstest3/sites/asmtportal/Lists/SearchList/AllItems.aspx

because this will always fall under the Rule URL.

Is there any other method to create a search scope that will search only through the items of a Single Sharepoint List in a site collection ??

Please tell me ,.. if there are any sharepoint experts ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely need to add a crawl rule to exclude that one page from being added to the index (which will then prevent it from being included in your search scope).